# Google Sheet out of space

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I use to record data that is entered from multiple users by using spreadsheet keys. The data recorded is queried daily by managers.

My sheet is out of space and I can no longer query the records. Is there anywhere that I can connect the google sheet that will allow for larger data sets?

Comment: Questions about general use of web applications are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se].

Comment: You could use a JDBC Connection to store all your data in a database perhaps and then query the database through a website on perhaps another JDBC connection.